# Checkbox styling issue with kendo treeview

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

The styling of the normal checkboxes works fine but when a checkbox is clicked in the tree the group checkbox of the tree is altered. It is a hyphen and I can't find a way to make it smaller. I have made the checkboxes smaller and now the hyphen looks weird in the checkbox. How Do I style that element with scss?

The picture below shows the current result

[image]

I tried the following code and that :before and :after parts works on th check icon and the checkbox sizes.

```
.k-checkbox {
  font-size: 8px;
}
.k-checkbox-label {
  font-size: 8px;
}
.k-checkbox-label:before {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-size: 8px;
}
.k-checkbox-label:after {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-size: 8px;
}
```

Ideally, I would like the group checkbox icon to always be the same as a checked checkbox. (It is if you click it first)

Comment: Do you have a stackblitz to share?

Comment: @DavideBellone https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-heudrq

Comment: maybe this can help https://www.telerik.com/forums/change-order-of-checkbox-and-icons-on-treeview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ezanker for showing me where to look. It wasn't enough to just set the width to 8px but tweaking that CSS rule made me able to change the line. I don't really know what is going on though and why it works.

The following css rule gave me the look I was after.

```
    .k-checkbox:indeterminate+.k-checkbox-label::after {
        width: 8px;
        height: 1.3px;
        top: 8px;
        left: 4px;
    }
```

The top and left center it because of the width of the checkbox that is 16px.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this CSS rule at the end of your styles.css:

```
 checkbox:indeterminate+.k-checkbox-label::after {
    width: 8px;
 }
```